# Is std::call_once lock free?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lock-free

I want to find out if the std::call_once lock free. [There](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117468/stdonce-flag-and-stdcall-once-implementation) are call_once implementations using mutex. But why should we use mutex? I tried to write simple implementation using atomic_bool and CAS operation. Is the code thread safe?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
using my_once_flag = atomic<bool>;

void my_call_once(my_once_flag& flag, std::function<void()> foo) {
    bool expected = false;
    bool res = flag.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true,
                                            std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if(res)
        foo();
}
my_once_flag flag;
void printOnce() {
    usleep(100);
    my_call_once(flag, [](){
       cout << "test" << endl;
    });
}

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i< 500; ++i){
            thread([](){
                printOnce();
            }).detach();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is at once a question about `std::call_once` and a question about reviewing your replacement implementation. Pick one question please.

Comment: Your implementation isn't thread safe because if `foo()` is in the middle of executing, `call_once()` needs to wait for it to finish.  There's no lock-free way to do that.

Comment: I want to understand if std::call_once lock free and whether it can be implemented lock free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proposed implementation is not thread safe. It does guarantee that `foo()` will only be called once through this code, but it does not guarantee that all threads will see side effects from the call to `foo()`. Suppose that thread 1 executes the compare and gets true, then the scheduler switches to thread 2, before thread 2 calls `foo()`. Thread 2 will get false, skip the call to `foo()`, and move on. Since the call to `foo()` has not been executed, thread 2 can continue executing before any side effects from `foo()` have occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

**The already-called-once fast-path can be wait-free**.

gcc's implementation doesn't look all that efficient.  I don't know why it isn't implemented the same way as initialization of `static` local variables with a non-constant arg, which uses a check that's very cheap (but not free!) for the case where it's already initialized.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once comments that:

> Initialization of function-local statics is guaranteed to occur only
>   once even when called from multiple threads, and may be more efficient
>   than the equivalent code using std::call_once.

---

To make an efficient implementation, the `std::once_flag` could have three states:

- execution finished: if you find this state, you're already done.
- execution in progress: if you find this: wait until it changes to finished (or changes to failed-with-exception, which which case try to claim it)
- execution not started: if you find this, attempt to CAS it to in-progress and call the function.  If the CAS failed, some other thread succeeded, so goto the wait-for-finished state.

Checking the flag with an acquire-load is extremely cheap on most architectures (especially x86 where all loads are acquire-loads).  Once it's set to "finished", it's not modified for the rest of the program, so it can stay cached in L1 on all cores (unless you put it in the same cache line as something that is frequently modified, creating false sharing).

Even if your implementation worked, it attempts an atomic CAS every time, which is ridiculously more expensive than a load-acquire.

---

I haven't fully decoded what gcc is doing for `call_once`, but it unconditionally does a bunch of loads, and two stores to thread-local storage, before checking if a pointer is NULL.  (`test rax,rax / je`).  But if it is, it calls `std::__throw_system_error(int)`, so that's not a guard variable that it's using to detect the already-initialized case.

So it looks like it unconditionally calls `__gthrw_pthread_once(int*, void (*)())`, and checks the return value.  So that pretty much sucks for use-cases where you want to cheaply make sure some initialization got done, while avoiding the static-initialization fiasco.  (i.e. that your build procedure controls the ordering of constructors for static objects, not anything you put in the code itself.)

**So I'd recommend using `static int dummy = init_function();` where dummy is either something you actually want to construct, or just a way to call `init_function` for its side-effects.**

Then on the fast-path, the asm from:

```
int called_once();

void static_local(){
  static char dummy = called_once();
  (void)dummy;
}
```

looks like this:

```
static_local():
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR guard variable for static_local()::dummy[rip]
    test    al, al
    je      .L18
    ret
 .L18:
    ... # code that implements basically what I described above: call or wait
```

[See it on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cthread%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmutex%3E%0A%0Astd::once_flag+flag1%3B%0A%0A%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0Astd::atomic_int+set_once(0)%3B%0A%0Aint+called_once()%3B%0A%0Avoid+static_local()%7B%0A++static+char+dummy+%3D+called_once()%3B%0A++(void)dummy%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23ifdef+USE_LAMBDA%0Avoid+do_once_lambda()+%7B%0A++++std::call_once(flag1,+%5B%5D()%7B+called_once()%3B+%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%23else%0Avoid+do_once_function()+%7B%0A++//+this+actually+compiles+to+worse+code+than+the+lambda%0A++std::call_once(flag1,+called_once)%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:30.114486822602625,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-DUSE_LAMBDA+-O3++-Wall+-fno-verbose-asm++-march%3Dhaswell'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.2',t:'0')),k:31.963621978376473,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g62,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3++-Wall+-fno-verbose-asm++-march%3Dhaswell'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.2',t:'0')),k:37.92189119902089,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), along with gcc's actual code for `std::once_flag`.

---

**You could of course implement a guard variable yourself with an atomic uint8_t**, which starts out initialized to non-zero, and is set to zero only when the call is complete.  Testing for zero may be slightly cheaper on some ISAs, including x86 if the compiler is weird like gcc and decides to actually load it into a register instead of using `cmp byte [guard], 0`.

Comment: There is an implementation of call_once that uses thread-local storage to avoid re-acquires; gcc may be using that. (Of course, since acquire is free on x86, I don't know why it would...)

Comment: @tony: thanks, that sounds like a plausible theory.  GNU libraries are not tuned exclusively for x86, and I wouldn't be surprised if it's just a generic C++ implementation.  And maybe it's not easy to get asm like compilers make for initializing a `static` using only portable C++ without actually initializing a `static`.  (I didn't look at all the docs for call_once, but IDK if its exception semantics match initializers for `static`.)  cppreference.com does warn that a `static` local variable might be more efficient, so maybe it's common for compilers to do stuff like this.

Comment: The use of static does not address the use case where the function to call once is a lazy initializer for a specific instance of a class or a struct. Example: struct A {  void get() {...}  void initOnce() {...} // other stuff };  Here I want that the first time get() is called on an instance of class A, initOnce is run for that instance.

Comment: @Fabio: So do it manually with a non-static member variable to track whether the lazy-init has been done for that instance.  Does it still need to be thread-safe?  i.e. is it allowed for two threads to run `foo->get()` on the same object at the same time?

Comment: I do not have any specific need, I was just commenting on the generality of the `static` solution. If I were to implement something different from `once_flag`, I would probably use a double-check with memory ordering, as in https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-6-double-checked-locking.html

Comment: @Fabio: yup, looks sensible.  As long as the already-initialized fast-path is wait-free (e.g. just an atomic acquire-load of a flag), it's very low overhead.  Then it's just a matter of deciding where to keep the flag.  Using `static` is just an easy way of getting the compiler to do all that for you if the flag can be global instead of per-object.