# Is std::call_once a blocking call?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std

I'm using `std::call_once` in my code to initialize some shared variables only once. The calling code is inside a callback that is triggered by multiple threads.
What I'm interested to know, since I couldn't find it in the documentation is whether `std::call_once` is blocking essentially as if there was a `std::lock_guard` instead? 
In practice it looks like this is the case.

For example, the following will print `"Done"` before any `print()` will be called:

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::once_flag flag;

void print()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
          std::cout << "Hi, my name is " << std::this_thread::get_id() 
            << ", what?" << std::endl;
    }
}

void do_once()
{
    std::cout << "sleeping for a while..." << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
}

void work()
{
    std::call_once(flag, [](){ do_once(); });
    print();
}


int main()
{
    auto handle1 = std::async(std::launch::async, work);
    auto handle2 = std::async(std::launch::async, work);
    auto handle3 = std::async(std::launch::async, work);
    auto handle4 = std::async(std::launch::async, work);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

I'm assuming this is indeed the case (since I don't see how it could be implemented otherwise), but is this behavior guaranteed or could there be a compiler that decides that `std::call_once` will indeed be called once but allow other threads to continue and just ignore this call?

Comment: _<...>since I couldn't find it in the documentation<...>_ What? It's the first sentence in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once): _Executes the Callable object f exactly once, **even if called from several threads**._

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I'm not a code lawyer but this doesn't mean that other threads must wait for the callable to complete before advancing to next line of code

Comment: "No invocation in the group returns before the above-mentioned execution of the selected function is completed successfully, that is, doesn't exit via an exception."

Comment: Not quite a dup, but insightful enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707149/is-stdcall-once-lock-free

Comment: @T.C., I'm having trouble understanding that sentence, could you make this into an answer and explain what group? what is the above-mentioned execution"?

Comment: `No invocation in the group returns before the above-mentioned execution of the selected function is completed successfully, that is, doesn't exit via an exception.` It is guaranteed to block until one of the functions passed to `call_once` with the same `once_flag` is done executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes `std::call_once` is a blocking call.  From [thread.once.callonce] we have

> *Effects:* An execution of call_once that does not call its `func` is a passive execution. An execution of call_once that calls its `func` is an active execution. An active execution shall call `INVOKE (DECAY_COPY ( std::forward<Callable>(func)), DECAY_COPY (std::forward<Args>(args))...)`. If such a call to func throws an exception the execution is exceptional, otherwise it is returning. An exceptional execution shall propagate the exception to the caller of call_once. Among all executions of `call_once` for any given `once_flag`: at most one shall be a returning execution; if there is a returning
>   execution, it shall be the last active execution; and there are passive executions only if there is a returning execution. **[ Note: passive executions allow other threads to reliably observe the results produced by the earlier returning execution. —end note ]**
>
> *Synchronization:* For any given `once_flag`: all active executions occur in a total order; completion of an active execution synchronizes with (1.10) the start of the next one in this total order; **and the returning execution synchronizes with the return from all passive executions.**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

This means that all calls to `call_once` will wait until the function passed to `call_once` completes.  In your case that means `do_once()` must be called before any thread calls `print()`