# Initialising with std::call_once() in a multithreading environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, initialization, std-call-once

I'm reading the book *C++ Concurrency in Action, 2nd Edition* <sup>X</sup>. The book contains an example that uses the [`std::call_once()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) function template together with an [`std::once_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) object to provide some kind of *lazy initialisation* in thread-safe way.

Here a simplified excerpt from the book:

```
class X {
public:
   X(const connection_details& details): connection_details_{details}
   {}

   void send_data(const data_packet& data) {
      std::call_once(connection_init_, &X::open_connection, this);
      connection_.send(data); // connection_ is used
   }

   data_packet receive_data() {
      std::call_once(connection_init_, &X::open_connection, this);
      return connection_.recv(data); // connection_ is used
   }

private:
   void open_connection() {
      connection_.open(connection_details_); // connection_ is modified
   }

   connection_details connection_details_;
   connection_handle connection_;
   std::once_flag connection_init_;
};
```

What the code above does, is to delay the creation of the connection until the client wants to receive data or has data to send. The connection is created by the `open_connection()` private member function, not by the constructor of `X`. The constructor only saves the connection details to be able to create the connection at some later point.

The `open_connection()` member function above is called *only once*, so far so good. In a single-threaded context, this will work as expected. However, what if multiple threads are calling either the `send_data()` or the `receive_data()` member function on the same object?

Apparently, the modification/update of the `connection_` data member in `open_connection()` is not synchronised with any of its uses in `send_data()` or `receive_data()`.

Does `std::call_once()` block a second thread until the first one returns from `std::call_once()`?

---

<sup>X</sup><sub>Section **3.3.1.**: *Protecting shared data during initialization*</sub>

Comment: There once was an interesting discussion of Meyers Singleton approach: [SO: Is Meyers' implementation of the Singleton pattern thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661529/7478597) which might be of interest.

Comment: `std::call_once` does synchronize with other calls to `std::call_once` on the same `once_flag` instance. That's kind of the whole point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054677/is-stdcall-once-a-blocking-call) I've created this answer.

I wanted to see whether `std::call_once()` synchronises with other calls to `std::call_once()` on the same `std::once_flag` object. The following program creates several threads that call a function that contains a call to `std::call_once()` that puts the calling thread to sleep for long time.

```
#include <mutex>

std::once_flag init_flag;
std::mutex mtx;
```

`init_flag` is the `std::once_flag` object to be used with the `std::call_once()` call. The mutex `mtx` is just for avoiding interleaved output on `std::cout` when streaming characters into `std::cout` from different threads.

The `init()` function is the one called by `std::call_once()`. It displays the text `initialising...`, puts the calling thread to sleep for three seconds and then displays the text `done` before returning:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void init() {
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx);
      std::cout << "initialising...";
   }

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{3});  

   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx);
      std::cout << "done" << '\n';
   }
}
```

The purpose of this function is to sleep for long enough (three seconds in this case), so that the remaining threads have enough time to reach the `std::call_once()` call. This way we will be able to see whether they block until the thread executing this function returns from it.

The function `do_work()` is called by all threads that are created in `main()`:

```
void do_work() {
   std::call_once(init_flag, init);
   print_thread_id(); 
}
```

`init()` will be only called by one thread (i.e., it will be called only *once*). All threads call `print_thread_id()`, i.e., it is executed once for every thread created in `main()`.

The `print_thread_id()` simply displays the current thread id:

```
void print_thread_id() {
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx);
   std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
}
```

A total of 16 threads, which call the `do_work()` function, are created in `main()`:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
   std::vector<std::thread> threads(16);
   for (auto& th: threads)
      th = std::thread{do_work};

   for (auto& th: threads)
      th.join();
}
```

The output I get on my system is:

```
initialising...done
0x7000054a9000
0x700005738000
0x7000056b5000
0x700005632000
0x700005426000
0x70000552c000
0x7000055af000
0x7000057bb000
0x70000583e000
0x7000058c1000
0x7000059c7000
0x700005a4a000
0x700005944000
0x700005acd000
0x700005b50000
0x700005bd3000
```

This output means that no thread executes `print_thread_id()` until the first thread that called `std::call_once()` returns from it. This implies that those threads are blocked at the `std::call_once()` call.